# Using 2 consensus algorithms

Tags: runtime

I'm trying to implement Layer 2 to Substrate. Substrate node runs BABE and GRANDPA to produce blocks and finalize.

Layer 2 comes built into the Substrate (planning to develop this way). It will have a faster slot-based block production and maybe finalization as well.

I'm thinking of having 2 consensus algorithms in parallel built into the Substrate node. Let's say that layer 2 produces 6 blocks for every block time for the Substrate node and sends the block proofs via runtime-api (or rpc).

[image: Visual explination]

I've hacked the Substrate to achieve this. First, added AURA to the node that has BABE. I separated the tasks so block production and finalization wouldn't affect different consensus algorithms. I didn't count for Prometheus. It compiled ok but got this error

> Failed to register proposer prometheus metrics: Duplicate metrics collector registration attempted.
> Essential task `basic-block-import-worker` failed. Shutting down service.

I haven't dug more after this. I'm questioning the possibility of this at this point.

- Should there be 2 separate runtimes? Or is the node's runtime
  enough?
- How would block finalization be done?

Comment: Sounds interesting, not an expert, but I think a layer-2 should have its own runtime and then just update the block_hash at regular intervals to layer-1. Anything more complicated than this you are just re-building a relaychain-parachain model. Also iiuc parachains can become their own relaychains in future.

Comment: I think you're right. Doing this in a single runtime could have bottlenecks. What I need and it's not possible atm is having a 2nd order Relay chain under the Kusama/Polkadot Relay chain. I've decided to go with 2 blockchains. Layer 1 will have room for layer 2 blockchains. Let's see where I'll end up

Comment: I am also working on hybrid consensus.
please let me know do u achieve your goal